# What's the name of the violin score played by Shaiapouf when Meruem is born?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

In the episode where the Chimera Ant King Meruem is born, Shaiapouf plays some vigorous music with his violin. I want to know the name of the song he played.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In episode 91 [*The Strong × And × The Weak*](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_91_(2011)), King Meruem is born. After his birth, he goes to the top of the ant hill where Shaiapouf plays a song titled [**In the Palace ~ Lamentoso**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7ZPdaqxsnU).

This particular song can be found on the [**Hunter × Hunter (2011) Original Soundtrack 3**](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter_(2011)_Original_Soundtrack_3) as track number 10.